# Solving Wave Equation with Initial Values

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

I am trying to solve the wave equation:

$u_{tt}$  = $u_{xx}$

With initial values:

$u(x,0) =\begin{cases} x^3 - x, &\text{for }|x|\le 1,\
\\0, &\text{for }|x|\ge1\end{cases}$

$u_t(x,0) =\begin{cases} 1 - x^2, \text{for } |x|\le 1,
\\ 0, \text{for } |x|\ge1   
\end{cases}$

In the domain $D= \{(x,t) | - \infty < x<\infty, \space\space t>0\}  $

I am using D'Alembert's Formula and after inputting the values in I have:

$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}[\frac{2}{3}(x+t)^3 + \frac{4}{3}(x-t)^3  - 2(x-t)] $

I am not sure where to go from here.

I think because the initial conditions are not differentiable at some points  then there will be points in the solution that are not differentiable

So I'd need to consider the different cases of $|x+t|\le 1$?

I could be going down the complete wrong path so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The tag ([tag:differential-equations]) is intended for questions about ordinary differential equations, there is a separate tag for [tag:pde]s; see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/differential-equations/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Comment: just to point out you may of made a mistake with D'Alembert's formula, as I get $$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{4}{3}(x-t)^{3} + \frac{2}{3}(x+t)^{3} - 2(x-t)\right]$$? Though it could be me with the mistake :).

Comment: Thank you @Chinny84 I've corrected the mistake, do you know where I go from here?

Answer (score 2):

In fact the real result should be $u(x,t)=\dfrac{f(x+t)+f(x-t)+g(x+t)-g(x-t)}{2}$ , where $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^3-x&\text{for}~|x|\leq1\\0&\text{for}~|x|\geq1\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}-\dfrac{2}{3}&\text{for}~x\leq-1\\x-\dfrac{x^3}{3}&\text{for}~|x|\leq1\\\dfrac{2}{3}&\text{for}~x\geq1\end{cases}$